# iOS UIWebView - No touchstart event after gestureend if a touch is still present

Tags: javascript, events, uiwebview, touch

When doing multiple touches in UIWebview i am unable to get a touchstart when i do the following:

Put two fingers on the screen. (This fires gesturestart)
Keep one of the fingers still, and lift the other (This fires gesturesend)

Put the finger that was lifted on the screen again and don't move any of the fingers while doing this (Nothing fires - i would say touchstart and gesturestart should fire here).

Touchstart and gesturestart fires as soon as one of the fingers are moved.

It seems to me that this must be a bug in UIWebView, and that it should be reported?

Is there a possible workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is in UIWebView it is generally also in every iOS browser (safari).

you can see the issue here: http://porsager.com/uiwebviewbug (only for devices with touchevent)